# Load function trie segmentation fault

Tags: c, null, segmentation-fault, trie, cs50

I keep getting segfault for my load function.

```
    bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    //create a trie data type
   typedef struct node
   {
        bool is_word;
        struct node *children[27]; //this is a pointer too!  
   }node;

   //create a pointer to the root of the trie and never move this (use traversal *)
   node *root = malloc(sizeof(node));
   for(int i=0; i<27; i++)
   {
       //NULL point all indexes of root -> children
       root -> children[i] = NULL;
   }


   FILE *dptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
   if(dptr == NULL)
   {
       printf("Could not open dictionary\n");
       return false;
   }



   char *c = NULL;


   //scan the file char by char until end and store it in c
   while(fscanf(dptr,"%s",c) != EOF)
   {
       //in the beginning of every word, make a traversal pointer copy of root so we can always refer back to root
       node *trav = root;

       //repeat for every word
       while ((*c) != '\0')
       {
        //convert char into array index
       int alpha = (tolower(*c) - 97);

       //if array element is pointing to NULL, i.e. it hasn't been open yet,
        if(trav -> children[alpha] == NULL)
            {
            //then create a new node and point it with the previous pointer. 
            node *next_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
            trav -> children[alpha] = next_node; 

            //quit if malloc returns null
            if(next_node == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Could not open dictionary");
                    return false;
                }

            }

        else if (trav -> children[alpha] != NULL)
            {
            //if an already existing path, just go to it
            trav = trav -> children[alpha];
            }   
       }
        //a word is loaded. 
        trav -> is_word = true;
   }
   //success
   free(root);
   return true;
}
```

I checked whether I properly pointed new pointers to NULL during initialization. I have three types of nodes: root, traversal (for moving), and next_node. (i.) Am I allowed to null point the nodes before mallocing them? (ii.) Also, how do I free 'next_node' if that node is initialized and malloced inside an if statement? `node *next_node = malloc(sizeof(node));` (iii.) If I want to set the nodes as global variables, which ones should be global? (iv.) Lastly, where do I set global variables: inside the main of speller.c, outside its main, or somewhere else? That's alot of questions, so you don't have to answer all of them, but it would be nice if you could answer the answered ones! Please point out any other peculiarities in my code. There should be plenty. I will accept most answers.

Comment: You need to debug your code, so you figure out which line your code segfaults at. You also need to do error handling and validation in your code. e.g. these lines:  `int alpha = (tolower(*c) - 97); if(trav -> children[alpha] == NULL)` is not something you can do, you have to know if your input is valid, so you have to check if `alpha` is `>= 0` and `< 27` before you can go on and use it as an index in `trav -> children[alpha]`

Comment: `char *c = NULL;` You've never allocated memory for `c`, so fscanf faults while writing in it.

Comment: `fscanf` wants a pointer to a place to store the incoming data. You have set `c` to `NULL` and pass that to `fscanf`, so when you read a line it tries to write through the null pointer. Create a line buffer, of, say, 256 chars, and pass that as the argument to `fscanf`.

Comment: Also, when you allocate a new node you don't zero the memory. Try calling `calloc` instead. Better still, write a separate function to allocate, initialize, and return the node pointer.

Comment: What would the return function do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of segmentation fault is the pointer "c" which you have not allocated memory.

Also, in your program -

```
//scan the file char by char until end and store it in c
while(fscanf(dptr,"%s",c) != EOF)
```

Once you allocate memory to pointer c, c will hold the word read from file dictionary.
Below in your code, you are checking for '\0' character-

```
   while ((*c) != '\0')
   {
```

But you are not moving the c pointer to point to next character in the string read because of which this code will end up executing infinite while loop.
May you can try something like this-

```
char *tmp;
tmp = c;
while ((*tmp) != '\0')
{
     ......
     ......
     //Below in the loop at appropriate place
     tmp++;
}
```